# Mapping storage data to object

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to implement a service repository. I know I could have used promises, but I don't know how to actually implement it. Here is my code:

```
export class Account {
    constructor(
        public id: String,
        public name: String,
        ) 
        { }
} 
@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
    constructor(private storage:Storage){}

    getAccount(id:any): Account {    
        var account : Account;
        this.storage.get("my-db").then((data) => {
            if(data && data[id]){
                account =  new Account(data[id].id,data[id].name);
        }
            else
                account =  new Account("","");
        });
       return account;
    } 
}
```

and when I use it:

```
...
constructor(public accountService:AccountService) {
   console.log(accountService.getAccount(1111));
}
...
```

it returns `undefined`.

What is the best practice to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait till promise gets completed and return promise from `getAccount` method.

```
getAccount(id: any): Account {
  var account: Account;
  //return from 
  return this.storage.get("my-db").then((data) => {
    if (data && data[id]) {
      account = new Account(data[id].id, data[id].name);
    } else
      account = new Account("", "");
    return account;
  });
};
```

**Component**

```
constructor(public accountService:AccountService) {|
   //though it could be better if you can shift this to ngOnInit hook
   accountService.getAccount(1111).then((account)=>{
      console.log(account)
   });
}
```

Comment: Wow! That was easy. Thank you.